# Jpa save entity after failed delete

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions, spring-data

I am trying to remove an entity and if it cannot be removed because of a constraint I want to mark it for logical removal.

This is my code:

```
  @Transactional
  public void removeEntity(EntityDto e) {

    Entity entity = entityRepository.findOne(e.getId());

    try {
      entityRepository.delete(e.getId());
      entityRepository.flush();

    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
      logger.debug("Logical removal");

      entity.setLogicalRemovalDate(new Date());
      entityRepository.save(entity);
    }
  }
```

After calling the save() method I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted instance passed to merge
```

Is there any way I can implement this functionality ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without doing it in a new transaction, with a fresh Hibernate session. [The documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation-exceptions) says:

> If the Session throws an exception, including any SQLException,
>   immediately rollback the database transaction, call Session.close()
>   and discard the Session instance. Certain methods of Session will not
>   leave the session in a consistent state. No exception thrown by
>   Hibernate can be treated as recoverable.

You should probably check that there is no other entity referencing the entity to delete before trying to delete it. Or simply always delete it logically, since it seems that it's what you're doing for referenced entities.

Comment: thanks, fixed by creating 2 Transactional methods, one for logical delete and one for the physical.